# How to access a variable's value that is inside onSuccess method of DocumentSnapshot of Firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I need to access a variable that is inside the onSuccess method of a DocumentReference to outside query.

```
DocumentReference documentReference = fStore.collection("Users").document(fAuth.getUid());
    documentReference.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
            final String admission = documentSnapshot.getString("Admission");
        }
    });
```

From the above code, I want to get the value of variable **admission** from outside of documentReference.

```
Query query = fStore.collection("studentAboutInfo").document("1234").collection("Leave");
    FirestoreRecyclerOptions<leaveStatusModalClass> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<leaveStatusModalClass>()
            .setQuery(query, leaveStatusModalClass.class)
            .build();
```

I need the variables value to be used in the above query. Both are inside onCreate method.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330766/why-does-my-function-that-calls-an-api-return-an-empty-or-null-value

Comment: Is `documentSnapshot.getString("Admission")` returning the correct value? If yes, why don't you pass that value to a method that does the exact thing you want?